# Delete Trigger with odd where parameters isn't working

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

In essence, I want to, upon adding a new player into the team, remove the previous player. I've tried emulating some of the stuff I found on here, but it didn't seem to work, which is why I'm making this question. I think it might have to do with my specific complex where clause?

The conditions for deleting is that it should be the same role, the same team, but different IDs. Different from the inserted player.

```
create or alter trigger retire2
on Players
after insert
as

begin

delete p 
from players p join inserted i

on p.playerid=i.playerid

where (p.TeamID=i.TeamID and
p.Role=i.Role and
p.PlayerID!=i.PlayerID);

end

go
```

Comment: `ON p.playerid = i.playerid ... AND
p.PlayerID != i.PlayerID` how can those 2 statement ever **both** be true?

Comment: But your schema is already logically flawed. Team and Player are different entities. You have mangled them into a single one. Role is also likely to be a different entity. You also make another assumption that is likely to become a problem eventually - there is no definition of "previous player".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have the clause `p.playerid = i.playerid` in your `ON` and `p.PlayerID != i.PlayerID` clause in your `WHERE` and define that both must be *true*. How can something not be equal to something, and be equal to something at the same time (ignoring quantum physics)?

I suspect what you are actually after is this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER retire2
ON dbo.Players
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    DELETE P
    FROM dbo.Players P
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM inserted i
                  WHERE i.TeamID = P.TeamID
                    AND i.[Role] = P.[Role]
                    AND i.PlayerID != P.PlayerID);

END;
```